# Detection of 'unfair' Bernoulli sequences using run lengths?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, bernoulli-distribution

I'm rather confused about the following question:

Which of the following vectors do you think is actually a random sample of $\mathcal{B}(1, 0.5)$ (Bernoulli) of length 10?
$[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]$ and $[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]$.

In the solution they argue that the second sequence is highly unlikely as the longest subsequence is of length 7 and highly unlikely.

I disagree with this answer as the likelihood of both sequences is exactly the same and in fact any sequence (including the constant sequence) has the same likelihood under $\mathcal{B}(1, 0.5)$.
However, this clearly clashes with my intuition as I would not think that $[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]$ is a random sample of $\mathcal{B}(1, 0.5)$.

Edit: I guess their solution does make sense if we consider the length of the longest subsequence as a summary statistic, and reject if the p value becomes too small. Still feels weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a 100 heads run surprising?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517340/why-is-a-100-heads-run-surprising)

Comment: If a Bernoulli sequence has $p=1/2,$ then a run of `1`s as long as seven does seem unlikely. Have you studied distributions of runs?  Also, at first glance it may seem unlikely to get seven or more heads in ten tosses of a fair coin, but the actual probability of that is about $0.17> 0.05 = 5\%$ [In R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, code `1 - pbinom(6, 10, .5)` returns $0.171875.]$  You are correct to observe that each of the $2^{10}$ possible outcomes from ten tosses is equally likely. In testing a null hypothesis, it is best to agree--before taking data--about the criterion for rejection.

Comment: The link does answers my question partially, thanks, although I'm still not confident to give a definite answer to the question posed in the exercise. I think that one of my core problems is that the criterion is chosen after taking the data as Bruce mentioned.

Comment: I think that weird feeling is legitimate, because the solution you quote is arbitrary.  Given *any* pair of finite sequences, one can construct *ex post facto* a relatively simple-looking criterion that makes either one of them seem more likely than the other according to that criterion. For instance, having a single `01` subsequence is three times *more* likely than having four such subsequences, allowing one to arrive at the opposite conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you decide **ahead of time** that you will reject
the null hypothesis that a coin is fair, if it has
a run of Heads or Tails that is $7$ or longer among ten tosses, then
what is the significance level of that test?

Put another way, what is the probability that a
fair coin will have a run of $7$ or more among ten tosses?

In R, the procedure `rle` (for *Run Length Encoding*)
provides as way to approximate this probability
by simulation.

Consider one experiment with ten tosses:

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rbinom(10, 1, .5)
x
 [1] 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:7] 2 1 1 1 1 3 1
  values : int [1:7] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

We see that there are seven runs, the longest
of which has length $3.$

Now we look at a $10\,000$ ten-toss experiments
to get an idea of the distribution of the length $W$ of the longest
run in ten independent tosses of a fair coin.

```
set.seed(320)
w = replicate(10^5, 
      max(rle(rbinom(10,1,.5))$len))
table(w)
w
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
  191 17251 36152 24492 12338  5590  2426   998   360   202 
mean(w >= 7)
[1] 0.03986
```

Thus it seems that the probability of getting a run of length seven or longer is about $0.04$ of 4%. So, according to the run-length criterion, we would
reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance.

There are theoretical results about run lengths
derived for use in such runs tests. You can google
`runs test` for discussions of distributions of run lengths.

The histogram below shows the approximate distribution of $W.$ The area of the bars to the
right of the vertical orange line is about $0.04.$

```
cutp = (0:10)+.5
hist(w, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = 6.5, col="orange")
```

[image]

*Note on R code for simulation:* The numeric vector `w`
contains maximum run lengths in 10,000 ten-toss
experiments. The logical vector `w >= 7` has
10,000 `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, and `mean(w)` gives
the proportion of `TRUE`s.

Comment: The question as stated does *not* posit such a prior hypothesis -- and that's the crux of the matter.  Testing hypotheses constructed by observing the data is HARKing.  The example in the question is an extreme form of that error.

Comment: Seems to me OP had already targeted that flaw. My answer shows that **in a proper context of a runs test**, a run of length seven is marginally good evidence that $p\ne 0.5.$

Comment: A [comment left by the OP](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568456/detection-of-unfair-bernoulli-sequences-using-run-lengths#comment1048406_568456) before your post expressly states otherwise: "I think that one of my core problems is that the criterion is chosen after taking the data as Bruce mentioned."

Comment: Reading it all again (tying for time order),I admit it difficult to discern whether OP is justifiably being critical of the claim in the text, whether OP is still hoping/imagining  there may be some justification for it. and whether OP is too reluctant (or 'polite') to criticize the text as clearly wrong.

Comment: I was indeed not sure if there might be some justification, but the [counterexample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568456/detection-of-unfair-bernoulli-sequences-using-run-lengths#comment1048414_568456) by @whuber makes it clear that this is indeed faulty reasoning if done after observing the data.